# I am trying to put some text in the PDF location I want. But it is not in the right position

Tags: python-3.x, pdf

```
Pdf.setFillColorRGB(0,1,0)
Pdf.setFont('Arial',Left_Font_Pt*inch)
# print('Word_List_Height',Word_List_Height)
Pdf.drawString((width-(Word_List_Width+5)),(Word_List_Height*len(List_Word)-0.1),text = List_Word[0])
for i in range(1,len(List_Word)) :
    Pdf.drawString((width-(Word_List_Width+5)),(Word_List_Height*(len(List_Word)-i)-0.1),text = List_Word[i])
```

I want to put List_Word to Bottom right  but it will exceed the Border